# ABOUT JOIN IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle10g

FIRST TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int PRIMARY KEY,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

SECOND TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder FOREIGN KEY (PersonID)
    REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

I FIRE THAT QUERY

```
SELECT PERSONID ,ORDERNUMBER, LASTNAME  FROM PERSONS P, ORDERS 0  
   WHERE P.PERSONID =O.PERSONID;
```

IT SHOW ERROR

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: `ORDERS 0` ... you used zero as a table alias.  As a side note, you should consider using an explicit join rather than putting commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: PERSONS DATA  ---PERSONID LASTNAME FIRSTNAME AGE
1 halson ola 30
2 Svendson tove 20
3 Pettersen kari 27-----

Comment: Btw, please don't shout, there are upper and lower case characters on your keyboard (UPPERCASE IS CONSIDERED SHOUTING).

Answer (score 1):

You defined the number zero as an alias, but then used capital `O`.  In the query below, I have resolved the alias problem, and I also replaced your implicit join with an explicit one using an `ON` clause.

```
SELECT
    pr.personid,
    od.ordernumber,
    pr.lastname
FROM persons pr
JOIN orders od
    ON (pr.personid = od.personid);
```

Comment: Just vote to close such typo questions, rather than answering.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen With all due respect to you, I did not vote to close the question because for a person who is asking a question here for the first time would not be aware that this is a typo question.

Comment: I disagree, because he uses capital `O` in the `WHERE` clause but zero when defining the alias.  It's a typo.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes Tim, there is a typo; does that mean we need to vote to close a question?

Comment: If the _only_ problem is a simple typo, then definitely close it.  It wouldn't benefit anyone else most likely.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PERSONID ,ORDERNUMBER, LASTNAME  FROM PERSONS P inner join ORDERS O  
  on P.PERSONID =O.PERSONID
```

Try this, Make sure you do not use statement terminator at the end as oracle does not use terminator.